# As a beginner, should I incorporate polarized training instead of HIIT or endurance as this study says?

Tags: training, triathlon

I'm a new triathlete, most in sprint distances. I go about 5 hours a week of training right now (im not that good yet) and will go more over the next year.

I read a study a friend gave to me (https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphys.2014.00033/full) and it says foing a combo of endurance traning and HIIT gives better results than just doing each of them alone.

it also says that they are really well trained guys, so would that make a difference for me as a beginner? Which type of training would produce better results?

Answer (score 1):

Research seems to give us two related findings. Here are a few examples:

**HIIT can be as good as endurance exersize in many ways**
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6683610/

**Combining HIIT with endurance training can be better than just endurance training alone**
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02640414.2016.1209539
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2095254616300813

Endurance atheletes that incorporate HIIT will likely notice an improvement in the intensity of their non-HIIT exersizes. For example, a long distance runner who practices sprinting on a regular basis might speed up overall. As a runner myself, I can say this is absolutely the case. It's also a common method employed by atheletes in various sports - your friend gives good advice.